# Will a method be called virtually even if no sub-class overrides it?

Tags: c++, call, virtual

Imagine you have the following classes:

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual void print()           { printf("A\n"); }
};
class B : public A {
  public:
    virtual void print() override  { printf("B\n"); }
};
class C : public B {
    // no override of print
};
```

And now if you create an instance of B and call print:

```
B * b = new B;
b->print();
```

Will this method be called virtually? In other words, will the exact method to be called determined at compile-time or run-time?

Theoretically it can be determined at compile-time, because we know, that none of sub-classes of B overrides that method, so no matter what I assign into pointer to B `B * b = new C; b->print();`, it will always call `B::print()`.

Does the compiler know it too and save me from unnecessary overhead of the virtual call?

Comment: Which is "the" compiler?

Comment: Probably implementation-specific - some, but not all, compilers would do the optimization you suggest.

Comment: Most likely will be optimized if it's in addition marked [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final), but I cannot say this with certainty as I don't know too much about the guts of compilers.

Comment: If you don't know how to find this out yourself so you *know* what your compiler does then you asked the wrong question.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: ah, i use standard GCC on Linux and MinGW on Windows

Comment: also, virtual functions has overhead, but 2~3 more assembly lines anyway. you load the v-table into some register, increment that register by some offset and you are done. you will have to call vritual functions milliards of times in order to see one second of a difference. usuall bottlenecks are non-friendly cache variables, memory allocations, heavy CPU and IO anyway, not virtual functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Theoretically it can be determined at compile-time, because we know, that none of sub-classes of B overrides that method

You cannot determine this at compile time in general case, because C++ compiler deals with one translation unit at a time. A class from a different translation unit, say, `class D : public B` could override the method. However, the compiler may have no visibility into the translation unit of `class D` at the time the call to `b->print()` is translated, so the compiler must assume a virtual call.

In order to address this shortcoming C++11 introduced [`final` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final), which lets programmers tell the compiler that there would be no further overrides down from this level of inheritance hierarchy. Now the compiler can optimize out the virtual call, and also enforce the requirement of no further overrides.

Comment: What if `final` is added?

Comment: With LTO the linker might be able to see it is unused and devirtualize it, I'd assume.

Comment: When casting to a specific type, the function call can also be de-virtualized. This is true, regardless of whether a function is overridden or not. In a way this is the brittle twin brother of `final`.

Comment: @IInspectable: I tried `static_cast<A*>(b)->print()` and also `dynamic_cast` and it still printed B

Comment: @Youda008: The virtual call **can** be optimized away. There is no requirement for a compiler to implement this optimization, but it would be legal. - On a second thought, though, I guess I was wrong. I was thinking of [Adventures in undefined behavior: The premature downcast](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120831-00/?p=6713). Sorry for the noise...

Comment: **−1** "You cannot determine this at compile time" is wrong. It could be correct to say that a call of a virtual function cannot always be determined at compile time.

Comment: Devirtualization is definitely a valid optimization, but it is extremely difficult to do, so you should not assume that your optimizer does it.

Comment: @Graznarak would you mind pointing out the specific language in my answer that suggests that I indeed make such an assumption?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you are correct that your answer does not make such an assumption.  I intended to point out that while there are certain optimizations that you assume that your compiler implements, devirtualization is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> **”** Theoretically it can be determined at compile-time, because we know, that none of sub-classes of B overrides that method, so no matter what i assign into pointer to B B * b = new C; b->print();, it will always call B::print().

**Yes.**

However, whether the compiler will do this optimization depends entirely on the compiler, what it knows, and what you tell it to do.

What the compiler knows depends on many factors, such as

- Are there classes defined in multiple translation units that are compiled separately?
- Are you using global optimization?
- Are you perhaps using the keyword `final` to inform the compiler?

With your specific example,

```
B * b = new B;
b->print();
```

where `print` is virtual, I would feel pretty confident that it would be called non-virtually regardless of compiler, because here the compiler *knows* what `b` refers to. Let's check.

OK, with MinGW g++ 5.1 and option `-O2` (I didn't try anything else) the call is compiled down to a direct call of `puts`, even bypassing the `printf`.

Comment: Just to be fair, your compiler calls `puts` directly because it has determined that `b` is of type `B`, not because it has determined that no overrides of `print` exist.

Comment: How do you check, which type of call was applied?

Comment: @Youda008: Depends. In this case I used the command line `g++ -O2 -S -masm=intel foo.cpp` and then inspected the assembly in `foo.s`.

Answer (score 1):

Standard aside, Modern compilers also have compile stuff like DLLs and shared libraries, and deal with a case of raw shared memory which other process `new`ed some object instance into.

so it is no uncommon to see a "Common" or "Shared" folder which hold an interface of some class , and two projects include that header and derived from that interface.

so in your example, let's say the whole declarations are in a header file, some other project may include that header and derive from `B`

this is how you can export a class pointer from a DLL and call the right function from shared libraries.

and as I wrote in the comment : 
virtual functions has a overhead, but 2~3 more assembly lines anyway. you load the v-table into some register, increment that register by some offset and you are done. you will have to call vritual functions milliards of times in order to see one second of a difference. usuall bottlenecks are non-friendly cache variables, memory allocations, heavy CPU and IO anyway, not virtual functions